# SQL inner join returns multiple values

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, with following values:

### tbl_a1

```
ID  Prod_Code   Prod_Sub    Prod_Note   Rec_Name    Prod_Qty    Prod_Flow   Rec_Mat_Act
306     111     1   falcon 1128     Stab120     25  5000    22623.17
307     111     2   falcon 1128     Stab120     25  5000    22635.52
308     111     3   falcon 1128     Stab120     24  5000    21623.89
309     111     4   falcon 1128     Stab120     27  5000    24439.78
311     111     5   falcon 1128     Stab120     27  5000    24402.79
313     111     6   falcon 1128     Stab120     24  5000    21582.37
315     111     7   falcon 1128     Stab120     14  5000    12654.76
316     111     8   falcon 1128     Stab120     27  5000    24447.1
317     111     9   falcon 1128     Stab120     25  5000    22613.14
318     111     10  falcon 1128     Stab120     23  5000    20759.74
```

### tbl_c1

```
ID  Prod_Code   Prod_Sub    Prod_Note   Rec_Name    Prod_Qty    Prod_Flow   Rec_Mat_Act
226     111     1   falcon 1128     Stab120     25  5000    1604.125
227     111     2   falcon 1128     Stab120     25  5000    1601.498
228     111     3   falcon 1128     Stab120     24  5000    1645.118
229     111     4   falcon 1128     Stab120     27  5000    1740.419
231     111     5   falcon 1128     Stab120     27  5000    1774.387
233     111     6   falcon 1128     Stab120     24  5000    1674.871
235     111     7   falcon 1128     Stab120     14  5000    918.7184
236     111     8   falcon 1128     Stab120     27  5000    1740.139
237     111     9   falcon 1128     Stab120     25  5000    1633.708
238     111     10  falcon 1128     Stab120     23  5000    1536.74
```

- e is unique and appears in both tables.
- `Prod_Code` is the unique production numbers Prod_Sub is the batch number (a prod_code can have several batch numbers)
- `rec_mat_act` is the actual used material in production

I'm trying to get a list with all unique prod_codes and their prod_sub and the used materials but I get duplicates results.

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT      a1.Prod_Code, 
            a1.Prod_Sub, 
            a1.Prod_Note, 
            c1.Rec_Mat_Act 
FROM        Tbl_Aggr1 as a1 INNER JOIN  Tbl_Cem1 as c1 
            on c1.Prod_Code = a1.Prod_Code  
WHERE       a1.Prod_Code = '111'
```

using a `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` didn't help me, neither did `GROUP BY` but maybe i'm using it all wrong.

Comment: please show table data and expected result

Comment: `GROUP BY` should give you the deserved outcome. Please provide your group by query

Comment: i have attached the tables

Comment: expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you put a distinct in the select it should just get the distinct prod_code from the first table and then all the resulting attached to it i.e:

```
select distinct
    a.prod_code, a.prod_sub, c.rec_mat_act
from tbl_a1 a
inner join tbl_c1 c on a.prod_code = c.prod_code
where a.prod_code = 111
```